# EditorTable Pivot View in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel App that happens to use the EditorTable (cousin to the DataTable from http://editor.datatables.net/). I can get the table to work fine with get and post but I have my SQL DB setup in w way where I need to make the editor dynamic. Basically I have a table that has a course code and semester year as well as a metric response that the end users will plug in at the end of each year.

How can I make the coding dynamic? Sometimes a course might have 5 metrics to show while another might have 15 in my DB. (Instead of making my SQL table static I made it a simple collector because of the classes being different.  I was thinking a for each loop but I could use some help here. Coding below:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                                        // Makes one continuous line - jsg 2/12/2016
            "scrollX": true,

            "autoWidth": false,
                                        // How many rows to return - jsg 2/16/2016
                "pageLength": 25,
                                        // Setup the search box with the current username to filter the values on the screen - jsg 2/12/2016
                "search": {search: '<?php echo $auth_id;?>' + ' INQ 300 '   },
                                        // End Search Setup populate
                dom: "Bfrtip",
               ajax: "../app/controllers/INQControllers.php"
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: null,
                        defaultContent: '',
                        className: 'select-checkbox',
                        orderable: false
                    },
                    { data: "fkey_instructor1_rcid", visible: false },
                    { data: "first_name" },
                    { data: "last_name" },
                    { data: "fkey_course_id" },
                    { data: "course_code"  },
                    { data: "course_number" },
                    { data: "course_section" },
              { data: "fkey_semester_id"},
              { data: "category"},
              { data: "Metric_text"},
              { data: "response_value"}

                ],

                order: [ 1, 'asc' ],
                keys: {
                    columns: ':not(:first-child)',
                    keys: [ 9 ]
                },
                select: {
                    style:    'os',
                    selector: 'td:first-child'
                },
                buttons: [

                    { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
              {
                  extend: 'collection',
                  text: 'Export',
                  buttons: [
                      'copy',
                      'excel',
                      'csv',
                      'pdf',
                      'print'
                  ]
              }
                    //{ extend: "remove", editor: editor }
                ]
            } );
               // Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
            $('#example').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
                editor.inline( this );
            } );

            // Inline editing on tab focus
             table.on( 'key-focus', function ( e, datatable, cell ) {
                 editor.inline( cell.index(), {
                     onBlur: 'submit'
                 } );
                          } );



            } );
```

This is where I'd like to make it dynamic if possible:

```
columns: [
                        {
                            data: null,
                            defaultContent: '',
                            className: 'select-checkbox',
                            orderable: false
                        },
                        { data: "fkey_instructor1_rcid", visible: false },
                        { data: "first_name" },
                        { data: "last_name" },
                        { data: "fkey_course_id" },
                        { data: "course_code"  },
                        { data: "course_number" },
                        { data: "course_section" },
                  { data: "fkey_semester_id"},
                  { data: "category"},
                  { data: "Metric_text"},
                  { data: "response_value"}
```

Table Headers:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                            <th>Instructor</th>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                        <th>Last Name</th>
                                          <th>Course ID</th>
                                <th>Code</th>
                                <th>Number</th>
                                <th>Section</th>
                              <th>Sesmenter</th>
                              <th>Category</th>
                              <th>Metric Text</th>
                              <th width="3%">Metric Value</th>
                                    </tr>
                        </table>
                                </thead>
```

My Ajax call:

```
Editor::inst( $db, 'gen_ed_assessment.responses_data_record')
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'fkey_instructor1_rcid' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'category' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'Metric_text' ),

        Field::inst( 'response_value' )
                 ->validator( 'Validate::values',  array('valid' => array("0.0","0.5","1.0","1.5", "2.0", "2.5","3.0", "3.5", "4.0"))),

        Field::inst( 'fkey_course_id' ),
        Field::inst( 'id' ),
        Field::inst( 'first_name' ),
        Field::inst( 'last_name' ),
        Field::inst( 'fkey_semester_id' ),
        Field::inst( 'course_code' ),
        Field::inst( 'course_number' ),
        Field::inst( 'course_section' )
```

Finally this is not a homework assignment I work for a College as a Database Admin and I'm touching into front end coding herewith php and laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out how I can go about making it dynamic, its not so much of a [EditorTable](https://editor.datatables.net/) as it is just making the data pivot. In Laravel 4.2 I was able to create a pivot in the blade and then make it editable.

```
{{ HTML::row() }}
  {{ HTML::col(12, 12, 12, 12) }}
  <h3>{{ $section->Description}}</h3>
  <h4>{{ $section->fkey_CourseCodeId }}- {{ $section->Number }}- {{ $section->ClassSection }}</h4>
  <th>Number</th>
  <th>Section</th>
  <th>Semester</th>
    {{ HTML::table(array('class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed datatable')) }}
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          @foreach($rubrics as $rubric)
            @foreach($rubric->metric_category->metrics as $metric)
              <th>{{ $metric->metric_text }}</th>
            @endforeach
          @endforeach
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($registrations as $registration)
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{$registration->RCID}}</td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    {{ HTML::closeTable() }}
  {{ HTML::closeCol() }}
{{ HTML::closeRow() }}
```